# jQuery selector exclude child table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the jQuery script try to remove the first column of a html table

```
var order_table = $('.hor-scroll').eq(1);
//alert(order_table.html());
var order_table_copy = order_table;

order_table_copy.find(".order-tables th:first-child").remove();     
order_table_copy.find(".order-tables td:first-child").remove();
```

but above script also remove the th, td of qty-table

the html

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="data order-tables" style="width: 100%;">
   <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
      <col width="1">
   </colgroup>
   <thead>
      <tr class="headings">
         <th width="1">Localisation</th>
         <th>Image</th>
         <th>Product</th>
         <th>Sku</th>
         <th><span class="nobr">Item Status</span></th>
         <th>Unit Price</th>
         <th class="a-center">Qty</th>
         <th>Subtotal</th>
         <th>Marge</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody class="even">
      <tr class="border">
         <td class="a-left"></td>
         <td class="a-center">
            <img src="" width="100px">
         </td>
         <td class="a-left">Laser Pants</td>
         <td class="a-left">test</td>
         <td class="a-center">Mixed</td>
         <td class="a-right">
            <span class="price-excl-tax">
            <span class="price">$64.99</span>                
            </span>
            <br>
         </td>
         <td>
            <table cellspacing="0" class="qty-table">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Ordered</td>
                     <td><strong>100</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Invoiced</td>
                     <td><strong>100</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Refunded</td>
                     <td><strong>9</strong></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="a-right">
            <span class="price-excl-tax">
            <span class="price">$6,499.00</span>                
            </span>
            <br>
         </td>
         <td class="a-center">
            0<span>%</span>    
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody class="odd">
      <tr class="border">
         <td class="a-left"></td>
         <td class="a-center">
            <img src="" width="100px">
         </td>
         <td class="a-left">Laser Hoody</td>
         <td class="a-left">test</td>
         <td class="a-center">Invoiced</td>
         <td class="a-right">
            <span class="price-excl-tax">
            <span class="price">$84.99</span>                
            </span>
            <br>
         </td>
         <td>
            <table cellspacing="0" class="qty-table">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Ordered</td>
                     <td><strong>100</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>Invoiced</td>
                     <td><strong>100</strong></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
         <td class="a-right">
            <span class="price-excl-tax">
            <span class="price">$8,499.00</span>                
            </span>
            <br>
         </td>
         <td class="a-center">
            0<span>%</span>    
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

but i can't exclude the qty-table, i had tried so many different but not work.

Comment: There is no class named `hor-scroll` in your html.

Comment: @Mamun considering that the code works removes something and that he is finding based on the `hor-scroll` selector, that class must be the content of the entire html he has shown. Showing it doesn't seem very necessary and may make the code much longer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/02a4chy1/1/ (full version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `order_table_copy.find(".order-tables th:first-child:not(.qty-table)")`

Also look into `:first-of-type`. And also remember that jQuery selectors returns an array. So if all else fails, you can always use the js `filter` function of arrays.

Update: To avoid the td the the `.qty-table`, make sure that the selected td is not a td under the `.qty-table`

```
order_table_copy.find(".order-tables tr td:first-child:not(.qty-table td)").remove();
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to NOT remove? i just checked, even in your original code the .qtr-table is not being removed

Comment: here is an update showing the table still there with css 
https://jsfiddle.net/02a4chy1/5/

Comment: <td>Ordered</td>,<td>Invoiced</td>,<td>Refunded</td>should be kept

Comment: I would have got this answer long back if I noticed you said "td of qty-table" and not "qty-table"